# Pivot operation is taking a longer time and never gets complete

Tags: azure, pivot, query-performance, u-sql

When we try to pivot large data set(12 GB of data) using USQL, which is expected to create an output of 3000 columns, it takes longer time to complete in USQL. The data is being read from Azure data lake store (ADLS) and written to ADLS also. The job is not running parallel even though we allocate more analytics unit (AU)

For smaller set of columns less than 100 columns the operation works like a charm. We need to extend this feature to 3000 columns.

**USQL Query - Sample code below**

```
@extractdata = EXTRACT  key string, source string, value string, timestamp string  FROM "input.txt" USING Extractors.Tsv();
@outputdata = SELECT * FROM (SELECT key, source, value, timestamp FROM @extractdata) AS D PIVOT(MAX(value) FOR source IN("38_3_1" AS [Label2_3_1],"38_3_2" AS [Label2_3_2],"38_3_3" AS [Label2_3_3])) AS P;
OUTPUT @outputdata TO "output.txt" USING Outputters.Tsv(outputHeader:true);
```

The keys like `38_3_1`, `38_3_2`, `38_3_3`.... `38_3_3000` goes upto `3000` with its corresponding labels.

**Input data sample, tab separated**

```
6029    38_3_1      190 1567116471000
6029    38_3_2      191 1567116471250
6029    38_3_3      192 1567116471500
```

The job is running for hours and never gets complete. In Azure data lake analytics, the job progresses up to 51% continuously then the progress is very slow. Has anyone faced similar problem? How did you handle if we need to produce report in tabular format with more than 3000 columns?

Comment: Are you having the same performance issue if you put your base table into a physical table (with indexes if needed), I've got some performance issues with Table Variable when they reach more than 1000 records.

Comment: @JonathanLarouche - Thanks for the quick check. Having it on physical table will not solve our problem. We were operating on top of azure data lake store with USQL and azure data lake analytics.

Comment: @AkhileshBalakrishnan insert your data into a table with possibly indexed columns and then do the pivot against the table. that is your best bet.